# Error installing Oracle on windows - inverted path bars

Tags: oracle11g, failed-installation

I know nothing at all about ORACLE.

I'm trying to install Oracle database 11 on windows 7 64 bit.

After following this tutorial

http://o7planning.org/en/10211/installing-and-configuring-oracle-database-11g

I get this error message

[image]

Having absolutely no clue about what is going on, I added ORACLE_UNQNAME=orcl to the environment variable in "system properties>environment variable" graphic interface.

I also ran this command on a command line window:

```
c:\> set ORACLE_UNQNAME=orcl
```

then I ran the command asked in the first error window:

```
emctl status dbconsole
```

and I got this answer:

```
C:\app\THIS-PC\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN>emctl status dbconsole
OC4J Configuration issue. C:\app\THIS-PC\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1/oc4j/j2ee/OC4J_D
BConsole_THIS-PC_orcl not found.
```

Notice that the path in the last error **has linux bars "/"**, which are inverted with respect to windows path bars: **"\"**.

Off course it will not find anything on that path.

I'm absolutely clueless on how to fix this. Can you help me?

Comment: The Oracle installer is a Java program, and thus using `/` for the path separator is not a problem. Java can even deal with mixing the `\ ` and the `/`